# Battling to find text within <br> tags using Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

We are currently developing a web-based application that sends an email to a user to validate his account.  I am new to Selenium and BDD and have so far been able to log into my web-based email account and I open the specific email.  However, the URL for activating my account is not a hyperlink, so I thought I could extract the text that contains the URL and open it as a link using Selenium.

Below is an extract of the email if I look at the source:

```
<div id="messagebody">
   <div class="message-htmlpart" id="message-htmlpart1">
        <div class="rcmBody">
             <img style="width: 150px" src="https://link/" />
             <br />
             <br />
             Dear Name
             <br /><br />
             A new profile was created at http://... using this e-mail address.  Please click on the link below to validate that the user profile can be created:
             <br />
             <br />
             https://athandwe.link/activate_account?uakey=1X7AP43W74AYDV9HUJSTRTVK8LOLA24

             <br />
...
```

I have tried several fixes but just cannot win:

```
1.  string info = currentDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='rcmBody']/text()[following-sibling::br]")).Text;

2.  string info = currentDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(text() ,'athandwe')]")).Text;

3.  string info = currentDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='rcmBody']")).Text;
```

I expect the result to be https://athandwe.link/activate_account?uakey=1X7AP43W74AYDV9HUJSTRTVK8LOLA24

Attempts 1 and 2 gave an error message - Text output versus Element expected error

Attempt 3 bring the entire body of the email across

Comment: have you tried the xpaths in googlechrome debugger?

Comment: Based only on what you've posted, _"it's not a hyperlink"_ because it's _not_ - it's just some text. IMHO, it'll be better, less brittle, if you did create an `anchor` element with the hyperlink with appropriate `id` etc so you can get to it easier in any case. Currently any change in your "email template" will potentially break whatever it is you're doing to "fix" it now. Hth.

Comment: Try `FindElement(By.CssSelector(".rcmBody")).GetAttribute("innerText");`

Comment: @toing_toing I originally tried the Chrome Debugger solution.  Tried about 10 different variations to try and get it to work, but always got the Output is text and the system is expecting an element

Comment: @EdSF That might be the best solution actually; to perhaps put an id on the br tag I am looking for.  I will speak to my developers

Comment: @Fenio Unfortunately I get an error that the Element cannot be found

Comment: @Jeremiah How about `FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='rcmBody']")).GetAttribute("innerText");`?

Comment: @Jeremiah Did you try the XPath?

Comment: @Fenio  I tried the xpath now and it returns the entire message in the body of the email.  I am trying to just get the hyperlink that is after the 5th <br /> tag.  The minute I try putting in ```/text()[preceding-sibling::br]``` I get an error that I am returning a text value when the system is looking for an element.

Comment: @Jeremiah The text does not belong in `<br>` tag. It's all a part of `div`. `<br>` is just a new line. I would just get the whole String and manipulate it to get results

Comment: @Jeremiah If you're working with your developers at this, have them make it an actual `anchor` tag `<a href="hyperlink_here"....` instead of **text** (that looks like a hyperlink). Don't confuse how some clients/apps _automatically detect **raw** text_ that _looks like a hyperlink_ and make it such. You're better off with _actual html elements/nodes_ that can be traversed/queried _structurally_ (instead of some "raw text")

Comment: @Fenio Given my very junior skills at development, manipulating the results would take ages.  Thanks for your guidance.  It is highly appreciated.

Developers made the change to create the <a> tag and my tests are now passing.  Thanks!

Comment: @Jeremiah Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Developers made the change to create the  tag and my tests are now passing.

Word of advice - When links are included in emails, make sure there is an anchor tag to identify the link if you want to click on the link as part of an automated test.